# Infinite product expression

Tags: complex-analysis

Define $f(z)=\cos z$

I want to write infinite product expression for $f(z)$

Please show how to write it explicitly.

I need to get the result $$\cos z=\prod _{k=0}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{4z^2}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2}\right)$$

Comment: Probably the product expansion of $\sin z$ or $\sin (\pi z)$ was derived in the lecture/book. The product expansion for $\cos z$ is derived quite similarly.

Comment: No I need to get the result $$\cos z=\Pi _{k=0}^{\infty} (1-\frac{4z^2}{\pi^2(2k+1)^2})$$

Answer (score 2):

Start by deriving that

$$\sin(z) = z\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left [ 1-\frac{z^2}{k^2\pi^2} \right ] \tag{1}$$

which can be done by showing $\int_{0}^{z} \left ( \cot t - \frac{1}{t} \right ) = \log \left (\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)$, and then replace $z$ by $2z$ in $(1)$ to get

$$\sin(2z) = 2z\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left [ 1-\frac{4z^2}{k^2\pi^2} \right ] \tag{2}$$

Now take the quotient of $(2)$ by $(1)$, and finish by applying double angle identity.

Comment: In the factors of the product in (2), the numerator should be $4z^2$ instead of $z^2$, I think.